# Can the function $S(\alpha)$ have a fixed point ordinal?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I feel like there is no fixed point of the successor function, as for any ordinal $\alpha$, the ordinal $\alpha \cup \{\alpha\}$ must be greater. Though maybe I’m wrong and some ordinals with inaccessible cardinality are so large that the successor function means literally nothing, so I thought I’d ask.

Comment: You are right, we always have $S(\alpha)>\alpha$.

Comment: So, there are no cases, aside from Cantor’s ‘true infinity’, without a successor ordinal, though I guess that would mean that it is the final limit ordinal as there would be no $\alpha + \omega$ for any $\alpha = S(\alpha)$.

Comment: Cantor's "true infinity" is not an ordinal

Comment: Nor a cardinal, it just doesn’t make sense, aside from being greater than all infinities.

Comment: There is no contradiction between $S(\alpha)>\alpha$ for all $\alpha$, and the fact that some ordinals can't be reached by applying $S$ to smaller ordinals.

Comment: @L. McDonald : Well it does make some sense - it is the proper class $\mathbf{On}$ itself. It has the structure of an ordinal, but is not a set, thus you cannot form its successor. (In ZFC, this object is only available in a "meta-" sense, but in an expanded set theory like NBG (von Neumann-Bernays-Goedel) it is a real object, however in NBG classes cannot be members of other classes and thus its successor will still fail to form.)

Comment: Why do you think that $S(\mathrm{Ord})=\mathrm{Ord}$? Or that $S(\mathrm{Ord})$ is even well-defined in $\sf ZFC$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every function can, or should, admit fixed points. Much like not every function from $\Bbb{R\to R}$ is continuous, or even continuous *at a single point*.

One condition which guarantees the existence of a fixed point is aptly named "normality". Recall that a function $f\colon\lambda\to\lambda$ is normal if $f(\alpha)\geq\alpha$ and for limit ordinals $f(\alpha)=\sup\{f(\beta)\mid\beta<\alpha\}$.

In that case, either $\lambda$ is of countable cofinality, or $f$ admits a fixed point (or both, of course). In fact, in case that $\lambda$'s cofinality is uncountable, one could argue that "most points are fixed points".

---

Of course, the successor function does not satisfy the second condition, which is known as continuity, since if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, $\sup\{S(\beta)\mid\beta<\alpha\}=\alpha<S(\alpha)$. Which is exactly why continuity is necessary.

I leave you to think why also the requirement that $f(\alpha)\geq\alpha$ is necessary.